# How to get the formatted string of printf?

Tags: c++, string-formatting

With `printf` we can print a formatted string to the console output.

**Question:** How can we get the formatted string as `std::string`?

Comment: `sprintf()` is probably what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You may use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) to convert it to a `char*` and then, use it to make a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) instead, but it will return a char*

```
int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
```